# Alfresco custom export in windows

Tags: export, alfresco

we are trying to have a partially export from Alfresco content.
we used below batch commands in windows which responses our needs.
but because of huge mount of Alfresco contents, we set our export such that
we have a partially content export, not all Alfresco Contents.
the problem is that, our partially export do not export previous versions of a content
and just export content latest version,
to export all versions of a content we forced to have a complete export which makes a huge mount of export content.
is there any solution?

> c:
>   cd C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF
>   set CPATH=../../../lib/*;../../../endorsed/*;lib/*;classes;../../../shared/classes;
>   java.exe -Xms128m -Xmx512m -Xss96k -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -classpath %CPATH% org.alfresco.tools.Export -user admin -pwd admin -s workspace://SpacesStore -path /app:company_home/cm:test -d d:/export -root -overwrite -verbose -zip export.acp

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can try this tool [Bulk Export](http://code.google.com/p/alfresco-bulk-export/) .

It's a free addon and should contain version support, if not it's probably quite easy to add it.

Comment: The code base has been migrated to github: https://github.com/gsdenys/alfresco-bulk-export